# Not redirecting for clean URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So I'm running into an issue here that I believe I have correct yet it's just not working for me here.

So simple enough I want me current URL which is: 
tremorelights.com/chandelier-c-18.html?page=2&osCsid=vtemi4nqlioftbteam6nap0s77

To look like this URL: 
tremorelights.com/chandelier/2/

So I'm trying to redirect it to the clean URL and this is what I have now.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^chandelier-c-18.html?page=$1 chandeliers/([0-9]+) [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Yet this is not working at all. When I manually input the clean URL it does not give me a 404 error but it does not take me to any other page like it should.

Comment: I think you have it backwards, don't you want `tremorelights.com/chandelier/2/` to redirect to `tremorelights.com/chandelier-c-18.html?page=2&osCsid=vtemi4nqlioftbteam6nap0s77`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match against the query string in a rewrite rule, what you want to match against is the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable here.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+chandelier-c-18.html\?page=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ chandeliers/%1? [QSA,L,R=301]
```

then maybe:

```
RewriteRule ^chandeliers/([0-9]+) chandelier-c-18.html?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hey Jon thanks for the help the redirect works. The only problem now is it continues to tack on these variables after the clean URL like this: `tremorelighting.com/chandeliers/2?cPath=18&page=2&osCsid=25msjgqd9qnss50e039m9k3j96`                          As you can see the clean URL is in place and I'm redirected to it but the ugly variables are still there.

Comment: Thank you for your help Jon. You've been a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^chandeliers/([0-9]+)/?$ chandelier-c-18.html?page=$1&osCsid=vtemi4nqlioftbteam6nap0s77 [QSA,L,NC]
```